# Save value of a check box

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two check boxes above the meta box text field in my wordpress theme add new custom post page. Every thing is working fine except when I refresh the page, both the checkboxes again become unchecked whereas I want one of them to be checked. Here is my html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" />
<input type="textarea" id="c" />
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
$('#a, #b').change(function () {
    var $a = $('#a'), $b = $('#b'), $c = $('#c');
    if (this.id == 'a' && this.checked) {
       $c.val('Hello World!');
       $b.prop('checked', false);
    } else if (this.id == 'b' && this.checked) {
       $c.val('Not hello World!'); 
       $a.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
       $c.val('');
    }
});
});
```

I don't know whether this is to be done through php or jQuery will be suffice and how to be done. Your help will be highly appreciated.
​

Comment: seeming you have to values you can use jquery to postthe values to a page check this link : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: [LocalStorage](https://github.com/palmerj3/PackageStore) is an option.

Comment: You can save that info in a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the html to be this?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" checked="checked" />
<input type="textarea" id="c" />
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I require. What I require is that when I first load the page to add my new post, both of these checkboxes should be unchecked and when I check one of them and publish my post, the value of the checkbox should also be saved.

Comment: Saved _where_ exactly? SQL database? Local storage? Flash storage? Cookie? Hair follicle storage?

Comment: Actually that is my WordPress site so it uses MySql database where I have to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes have no `name` attribute, so they can't be saving.

If you are not familiar with meta boxes enough, you should use a library that does them. There are many out there, I even have one - [mr meta box](https://github.com/mrfoto/mr-meta-box).

Comment: Thanks Miha, I have checked your liabrary and it's wonderful. But I have used name attribute as well but still not saving the value.

Comment: That only means you are not saving it. Again, if you are not comfortable with meta box syntax, do not do them on your own.

Comment: Yes that's what my question is all about how to save it.

Comment: Read [this](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) and tripple check your code.